# Disable additional exception logging as System.err in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j2

I'm trying to log all log messages in json format, but my application logs all exceptions additionally as System.err.

My log4j2 config looks as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:gelf-layout.json" locationInfoEnabled="true"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

If exception is thrown I see this log output:

```
{"version":"1.1","time":"2024-01-04T14:37:06.086+0100","level":6,"short_message":"Error 404 occured ","stack_trace":".........}}

Jan. 04, 2024 2:37:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
ERROR: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is de.mycompany.exceptions.Server5xxCommunicationException: Fehler beim Erstellen einer Info.] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:208)
    at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$MapN.<init>(ImmutableCollections.java:1186)
    at java.base/java.util.Map.of(Map.java:1395)
```

JSON-Format looks good but I would like to disable additional error logging below the json log output.

Even if I disable log4j2 logging completely there are no logs except of  this error message in console.

```
Jan. 04, 2024 2:37:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
ERROR: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is de.mycompany.exceptions.Server5xxCommunicationException: ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time struggling with this stacktrace I was able to disable java.util.Logging for `org.apache.*` in SpringBootApplication.
Now it works as it should

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {Logger geloggt werden.
   var logger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache");
   logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
   SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```